# copying without attribution

Tags: discussion

How should I report instances of copying Server Fault content to other question and answer sites when the content has been copied without attribution as per this post http://www.experts-exchange.com/Hardware/Networking_Hardware/Switches/Q_27754282.html#a38077737 which contains information from this Server Fault post [Is it possible to match an internal IP address to a switch port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/10573/is-it-possible-to-match-an-internal-ip-address-to-a-switch-port)

Answer (score 2):

You've done what you need to (which is making the community aware; the official SE people drop past here fairly regularly). The issue with experts exchange is that, like this site, it's user submitted content.

SE does go after the people who scrape the site or use the API/Data Dump for their own profit *without proper attribution*. The case with EE though is like someone here copy/pasting from EE. Not that much anyone can do about it.

I don't know if EE has an abuse/flagging mechanism, but if so, it might be worth using it.

(fwiw now that EE has done away with their "scroll through 500 pages of fluff and eventually you'll find the answers, I can't actually see the linked post as I'm not a member)

Comment: I have already flagged it to EE, but thought it only "proper" to inform SF as well. Thank you for replying so quickly.

Comment: Set Google as your referrer and you'll get access - the easiest way is to do a Google search for the URL in question.

Comment: All user-generated content at SE is licensed under a "Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 2.5 Generic License" which explicitly requires attribution for copied content. Disregarding this requirement would result in a license violation. I have no idea if anybody is pursuing such "small-scale" CC license violations, but if EE allows for answer editing, adding the necessary attribution to the answer would be the easiest route to go. I do not know much about EE and the license the content is distributed under, but CC-SA also requires it to be under a license "same or similar to this one".